# How to handle HTTP 429 in my Spring Boot App?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application uses a REST endpoint.

This endpoint returns a `HTTP 429 (too many requests)` at high load.

What is the best way to handle it?

Does Spring Boot offer possibilities here?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of spring you use.

If you use reactive streams (e.g. [webFlux framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html)) then you can use [backpressure mechanism](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure).

If not, you can use for example [resilience4j](http://resilience4j.github.io/resilience4j/#_ratelimiter) ratelimiter and bulkhead mechanism.

Comment: We use Spring Boot 2.x and the RestTemplate for requesting the REST endpoint. Thanks for the hints. Have for any examples for the resilience4j ratelimiter on SB?