Avoiding the SPAM while sending a specific request using Java or SpringBoot
just a quick question in order to get some idea of what are the standards and what can be implemented.
AS-IS:
I have a webpage with a button.
When I click on a button a request gets sent : A POST request and I return a json with a message : Request sent
If I click again the button I send the request again.
TODO :
I click on the button and the request gets sent. the json shows me : Request sent
If I click again I get a 429 not a 200 and the json says : You already did the request please wait 5 minutes.
My question is :
Is there any any spam standard method to do so or I just have to come up with my own fix like implementing some ConcurrentHashMap or use cache or check the time and based on that return a different http response with a different body ?
Hope the question makes sense.
Thx in advance for all the ideas and help.
Wish you a good day.

Looks this is similar to another one asked on Rate-Limiter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059475/how-to-handle-http-429-in-my-spring-boot-app
